# Find elements values are unique and all elements are same in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

Find elements values are unique and all elements are same in the list.

```
  >>> a = ['1','1']
  >>> all(x == a[0] for x in a)
  True
  >>> a = ['1','2']
  >>> all(x == a[0] for x in a)
  False
  >>> a = ['1-2-3','1-2-3']
  >>> all(x == a[0] for x in a)
  True

  #### Diffent Example #####################
  >>> a = ['1-2-2','1-2-2']
  >>> all(x == a[0] for x in a)
  True
  Expected Output False.

  any elements must contain unique values, but here it is repeated that is 2-2.
```

list format always:

```
   a = ["1", "2", "3","4"]
   b = ["1-2-3", "1-2-2"] # That is dash separated
```

Comment: `a = ['1-2-2','1-2-2']` the array has two identical elements, both of which are strings. It's not clear why do you expect `all(x == a[0] for x in a)` to return `False`

Comment: "Expected Output False" why do you expect that?

Comment: what do you mean by 'Unique' and 'same' in list?

Answer (score 2):

You can try with additional condition to split on `-` and check if length matches with `set` as compared to `list` i.e. add `(len(x.split('-')) == len(set(x.split('-')))`:

```
>>> a = ['1-2-2','1-2-2']
>>> all((x == a[0]) and (len(x.split('-')) == len(set(x.split('-')))) for x in a)
```

Result:

```
False
```

For other example:

```
>>> a = ['1-2-3','1-2-3']
>>> all((x == a[0]) and (len(x.split('-')) == len(set(x.split('-')))) for x in a)
```

Result:

```
True
```